# session error in PHP because pear path

Tags: php, xampp

In my project, I'm using the `session_start()` from PHP, but analyzing my code and the print error, I understand that wasn't because my code, and yes because a path from the content, I'm using the Xampp.

This is the error bellow:

> Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>
> Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:/xampp/htdocs/.../index.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Apparently your script is trying to require/include `C:/xampp/htdocs/.../index.php`, which does not exist (hence the "No such file" error).

Comment: your page is saved in the root of htdocs folder?

Comment: PEAR just happens to be in your `include_path` directive. I see no reason to suspect it's related to your problems. Can you reproduce it with a simple standalone test script?

Comment: Have you defined in `php.ini`, `.user.ini`, `.htaccess`, `httpd.conf`... any PHP directive that involves loading a file, such as `auto_prepend_file`?

Answer (score 0):

This only happens when a [ href ] link is referenced with a word that has a letter that has an accent on it example on the word header below:

```
<?php require("templates/heáder0.php"); ?>
```

the ` on the A on the word header where it is being referenced should/must not be there. even if the link is written properly, but if the filename is written with any letter with an accent like áÀã:

PhP will not see that file or it will not compile it

that is the reason to that error.

Hope i helped.